Which sampradaya's traditions are followed at the Sri Jagannath Mandir in Puri?
In my recent visit to the Sri Jagannath Mandir in Puri, I witnessed a lot of symbols resembling the tilak of Sri Sampradaya. At the same time, there was a cabin near the Singha dwara for the Sankracharya of the Advaita tradition. I could find a lot of devotees with the tilak of Gaudiya Sampradaya. And the tilaks of the temple priests were miscellaneous.
Can someone shade light on this aspect?

Since Adi Shankara recovered Puri, the Shakaracharya of Puri has a pre-eminent position in managing the temple. However, rituals like Navakalebara, Rathayatra, cooking of naivedya etc etc are extensively dealt with in  the Pancharatra, influence of Ramanuja is bound to be seen. And since the days of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu, Jagannatha has been worshipped through the 18-lettered Krishna mantra (described in Haribhaktivilasa), for previously it was the Purushottama mantra (described in Prapanchasara Tantra) & Narayana mantra (described in Pancharatra).

Most of Odiya Hindus follow Vaishnavism, which although loosely associated with Gaudiya Vaishnava sampradaya, is heavily influenced by the works of the Panchasakhas written in vernacular Odiya than the Sanskrit works of Bengali Gaudiya Vaishnava acharyas. Hence the use of Gaudiya Vaishnava tilaka is observed in Odisha.
